# why subprocess.Popen cannot work when it run under service/init.d?

Tags: python, service, subprocess

I have these code in a file "code.py"

```
param_list = ['/usr/bin/someapp.bin','-q','/usr/bin/someparam.conf','/tmp/output.pdf']
p = subprocess.Popen( param_list , shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
p.communicate()
```

the someapp.bin will produce a file and output as /tmp/output.pdf
when i run under the code.py under terminal shell , it works ,
and the user is : **ubuntu**

but when i try run it as a service using user : **service_user**
and make sure the /tmp folder is writable and accessible for anyone.

my question is why it just cannot generate as it suppose to be under
service , my suspect is permission issue but i just cannot get it to
work and need some advice and help , thanks.

Comment: You didn't say what happens or what error you get

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're running as 'service_user'? Maybe verify with os.getuid(). If so maybe log on as service_user and try running the script in a terminal, if it doesn't work I agree it's probably a permissions issue. You could also see what happens if you run the script with sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work. To track down the issue:

1. Add `print(os.getuid())` to the code to make sure it's started with the UID that you expect
2. Enable logging/debugging for `someapp.bin` to see whether there is an error
3. Examine the exit code
4. Print the output of the command to the console so you can *see* any errors:

   ```
   output = p.communicate()[0]
   print(output)
   ```

Comment: HI, thanks for trying to help , i can confirm that the above code is working under user **ubuntu** but when i started it as service , init.d using a different user **service_user** , it does not work , i can print the os.getuid when i run under shell using user **ubuntu** , but when i run as service , as it will capture into log file somehow the print command cannot be captured into the log file so i cannot check it. And i assumed that the service called belong to the **service_user** by checking under running processes the owner.

Comment: when i login using **service_user** and run the same command , i found some error and got it fixed ! , thanks to all.